# Invoke method from other gradle script

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to have methods to generate build number and version outside build.gradle. I've created build-versioning.gradle:

```
def getNewBuildCode = { ->
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'rev-list', 'HEAD', '--count'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    def version = stdout.toString().trim().toInteger()
    println("versionCode: $version")
    return version
}

def getVersionNameFromTag = { ->
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--tags'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}
```

Then I'm applying it in build.gradle by:

```
apply from: '../../signing.gradle'
```

and using in defaultConfig:

```
versionName getVersionNameFromTag()
```

I'm reciving:

```
Error:Could not find method getVersionNameFromTag() for arguments [] on ProductFlavor_Decorated{name=main, dimension=null, minSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=17, mCodename='null'}, targetSdkVersion=DefaultApiVersion{mApiLevel=24, mCodename='null'}, renderscriptTargetApi=null, renderscriptSupportModeEnabled=null, renderscriptSupportModeBlasEnabled=null, renderscriptNdkModeEnabled=null, versionCode=157, versionName=null, applicationId=ae.propertyfinder, testApplicationId=null, testInstrumentationRunner=android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner, testInstrumentationRunnerArguments={}, testHandleProfiling=null, testFunctionalTest=null, signingConfig=null, resConfig=null, mBuildConfigFields={}, mResValues={}, mProguardFiles=[], mConsumerProguardFiles=[], mManifestPlaceholders={}} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.ProductFlavor.
```

The same with getNewBuildCode.
How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***def*** indicates local functions/variables so you have to export them. this can be done via the ***ext*** property. Find more about it here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#sec:local_variables

```
ext.getNewBuildCode = { ->
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'rev-list', 'HEAD', '--count'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    def version = stdout.toString().trim().toInteger()
    println("versionCode: $version")
    return version
}

ext.getVersionNameFromTag = { ->
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'describe', '--tags'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It shoul look like this:

```
// build.gradle file
task build(type: GradleBuild) {
    buildFile = 'other.gradle'
    tasks = ['hello from main file']
}
// other.gradle file
task hello << {
    println "method from another file here."
}
```